# How to enable debug mode in tuleap?

Tags: tuleap

Could you help to enable debug mode in tuleap?
 We need to monitor what are the files and functions were run while trigger any event in tuleap,For example if i search an artifact i have to monitor what are the files and functions was run.
Kindly provide needfull help ASAP

Comment: did you read the [docs](https://tuleap-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/developer-guide/dev-setup.html#debug-profiling)?

Answer (score 0):

The only debug mode that I know in Tuleap can be activated as described in the [FrequentlyAskedQuestions on tuleap.net](https://tuleap.net/wiki/?group_id=101&pagename=FrequentlyAskedQuestions).
You also need to set a parameter in the /etc/tuleap/conf/local.inc:

> $sys_logger_level = 'debug';